# Why cant I set a property of a pointf in a list?

Tags: vb.net

Test class:

```
Public Class durp
    Public somelist As New List(Of PointF)
    Public Sub stuff()
        somelist.Add(New PointF)
        somelist(0).X = 5
    End Sub
End Class
```

It tells me on the line somelist(0).x = 5 that "Expression is a value and thefore cannot be the target of an assignment"

wat?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properties in Structures: "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021810/properties-in-structures-expression-is-a-value-and-therefore-cannot-be-the-tar)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expression Is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/681464/11683)

Comment: Great.. turns out, what happens is that the default property of List returns a copy of the value type pointf and manipulating that is useless. Just one of them shortcomings of managed code I guess...

Comment: @user81993 This has nothing to do with List or managed code itself, and everything to do with the behavior of value types (like structs). If you put a reference type into a List, it will return a reference type as the default property.

Comment: @MikeHofer I disagree, with c++ it would be possible to return a pointer for any struct/class while you cant return a reference to a value type in vb.net

Comment: @user81993 You confuse your language (VB.NET) with the Common Type System, which is only one component that .NET is built on (along with the Common Language Infrastructure, and a number of other key components that provide a means for many different languages to fairly seamlessly work together). It's the CTS that separates value and reference types, and *does* provide a means for converting one to another (boxing and unboxing). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcx1eb1e(v=vs.110).aspx for more information.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use the List(), then create your own version of PointF that is a Class instead of a Struct.

Otherwise, create a local variable, modify it, then put it back in:

```
Public Sub stuff()
    somelist.Add(New PointF)

    Dim ptF As PointF = somelist(0)
    ptF.X = 5

    somelist(0) = ptF
End Sub
```

Alternatively, build up your list then convert it to an array.  Then you can use it directly like you originally planned:

```
Public Class durp

    Public somearray() As PointF

    Public Sub stuff()
        Dim somelist As New List(Of PointF)
        somelist.Add(New PointF)
        ' ... add a bunch more points somehow ...

        somearray = somelist.ToArray
    End Sub

    Public Sub stuff2()
        somearray(0).X = 5
    End Sub

End Class
```